# What does quote mean in this case?

Tags: meaning, quotations

I am having a correspondence with an online shop and we are discussing shipment of a batch of goods to them. My English isn't perfect, so before asking them what they mean (and appear stupid) I'd like to ask here first.

> we'd be happy to purchase a batch or a case depending on our cost. Could you please provide a **quote** including shipping for one case (around 12 games or so, we are flexible with that if a case is smaller or larger) to post code .....

Do they mean they want me to send them a parcel and provide a confirmation of the fact of sending?

UPDATE: are they referring to the most current price of sending a case to their postal zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**quote**, 2: *to estimate what a cost or price is likely to be*](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/quote.html)

They mean that they want you to provide a *price quote*, a statement of what the batch or case will cost, *plus* the cost of shipping it.